# getchar() with non-canonical mode on UNIX and Windows

Tags: c, windows

I want to the record user's input, printing it as `*` until ENTER key is pressed. For that purpose, I disable the echo and canonical mode for keyboard, and then use some code like this:

```
while ((aux = getchar()) != '\n')
{
    buffer[i++] = aux;
    printf("*");
}
buffer[i] = 0;
printf("\n");
```

This code works perfect on UNIX systems, but not in Windows. To guess what the problem could be, I wrote this pieces of code for each platform:

UNIX

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main ()
{
    int c;
    struct termios mode;

    tcgetattr(0, &mode);
    mode.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON);
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &mode);

    while (1)
    {
        c = getchar();
        printf("%d\n", c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Windows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main ()
{
    int c;
    DWORD mode;
    HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    GetConsoleMode(console, &mode);
    SetConsoleMode(console, mode & ~(ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT | ENABLE_LINE_INPUT));

    while (1)
    {
        c = getchar();
        printf("%d\n", c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result in UNIX is that, each time I press ENTER, I get the number 10. That's perfect. But the result in Windows is:

1. First time I press ENTER, `printf("%d\n", c)` substitutes `%d` by nothing.
2. Second time I press ENTER, `printf("%d\n", c)` substitutes `%d` by 13.

I think that the problem may be related with the fact that new line characters are represented in Windows as CR+LF, but I don't know how to handle this to detect the first time that the ENTER key is pressed to make the first snippet of code work.

Comment: As you need a separate version for Windows anyway, you could use `_getch()` and simply translate every `13` into `10`.

Comment: For using `getchar`, you could set `STDIN` to binary mode via `_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY)`. Then the console will consistently return 13 (CR) every time enter is pressed. No translation is done to convert this to 10 (LF), unlike a Unix terminal.

Answer (score 3):

On Unix, disable the `ICRNL` bit in `termios`'s `c_iflag`. Then you will get `'\r'` on both platforms.

Answer (score 2):

In windows you can use `getch()` declared in `conio.h` instead of `getchar()` for what you want.

Example code:

```
 #include<conio.h>
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
 int aux,i=0,buffer[MAX];
 while ((aux = getch())!=13)
 {
  buffer[i++] = aux;
  printf("*");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `_getch` is only for the console. You'd have to fall back to `getchar` if stdin isn't a tty, i.e. redirected to a pipe or file. You can just set `stdin` to binary mode at startup to always use `getchar`.

Comment: However, there are at least two exceptions when using `getchar` in binary mode. Even if you disable both line input and processed input, the console always ignores escape and line feed (i.e. Ctrl+J) characters for a `ReadConsole` or `ReadFile` request. You can only read those keys as console input with a low-level `ReadConsoleInput` call, which is what `_getch` does.